# Redirect based on country

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect

I would like to host a webpage on Github, which does not support php, and then redirect all visitors, except those in China, to another website (hosted on Weebly).

The reason is that Weebly is blocked in China but provides a better user experience.

How can I do that without PhP enabled? Is there a way to do that in Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [geoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/examples)

First Add

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to your webpage

then try this

```js
document.write("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_countryName());
```

```html
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ipinfo.io

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', '//ipinfo.io', true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (obj.country != 'CN')
                window.location.replace('http://www.weebly.com/...');
         }
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: This will require jquery but he said javascript

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi you are right. i've just converted it to pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.write("Welcome to our visitors from "+geoplugin_countryName());
```

```html
 <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function geo(a) {
switch (a.country.code)
{
   case "SE": // Redirect is visitor from Sweden
   case "NO": // Redirect is visitor from Norway
   case "FR": // Redirect is visitor from FRANCE
   case "PL": // Redirect is visitor from POLAND
   case "GY": // Redirect is visitor from GERMANY
       window.location = "https://se.brixtol.com" + window.location.pathname; // edit for your URL
       break;
   default: 
       return null;
}
}
</script>enter code here`
<script src="https://geoip.nekudo.com/api?callback=geo"></script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation - don't just post a plain code block