# Shopify: How to redirect users based on their geo location?

Tags: shopify

I am new to Shopify.

1. Where can I access the code of my Shopify store?
2. How to redirect users based on their geo-location?
3. Where should I put the redirecting code?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at Shopify docs, they are surprisingly extensive and accurate:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/using-themes/change-the-layout/theme-code

As for redirection, I think it has already been answered:
[Redirect based on country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987953/redirect-based-on-country/51624243)